# Incomplete JSON string is returned from PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, geojson

The following SQL statement returns a single row (a JSON string)

```
Select jsonb_build_object(
    'type',     'FeatureCollection',
    'features', jsonb_agg(feature)
)
    FROM (
        SELECT json_build_object(
            'type',       'Feature',
            'properties', json_build_object(
                'cell', cell,
                'value', value
            ),
            'geometry', ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::json
        ) as feature
            from (
                select dgg.*, trunc(random() * 9 + 1) as value 
                    FROM mj_dgg_regions_BB($1, $2, $2, $3, $4) as dgg) row
    ) features
```

If I put this statement in a function (see below), the resulting JSON string is incomplete

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mj_dgg_regions_BB_geojson(res int, xmin float, ymin float, xmax float, ymax float) 
RETURNS json AS $$
begin
return(
Select jsonb_build_object(
    'type',     'FeatureCollection',
    'features', jsonb_agg(feature)
)
    FROM (
        SELECT json_build_object(
            'type',       'Feature',
            'properties', json_build_object(
                'cell', cell,
                'value', value
            ),
            'geometry', ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::json
        ) as feature
            from (
                select dgg.*, trunc(random() * 9 + 1) as value 
                    FROM mj_dgg_regions_BB($1, $2, $2, $3, $4) as dgg) row
    ) features
);
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The result is again a single row containing a JSON string. However this string does not contain all the entries that the first statement (no function) contained.

Since there is no error message, I am a bit lost.

**EDIT 1:**

To rule out problems with psycopg2 and DBeaver I tried it with psql

```
psql -U USER -d DATABASE -c "copy (select mj_dgg_regions_BB_geojson(4, 10, 10, 60, 60)) to stdout;"
```

This returns the same truncated result. Calling the statement alone returns the correct (full length) JSON string, calling the function does not. My guess is, therefore, that the function is not correct.

**EDIT 2:**

mj_dgg_regions_bb() is essentially a spatial query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mj_dgg_regions_bb(res integer, xmin double precision, xmax double precision, ymin double precision, ymax double precision)
 RETURNS TABLE(cell bigint, geom geometry)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT dgg.cell, dgg.geom::geometry FROM regions as dgg
        where dgg.res = $1 
        and
        dgg.geom::geometry &&
            -- && -- intersects
            -- @ -- contained by
        ST_MakeEnvelope (
            $2, $3, -- bounding 
            $4, $5, -- box limits
            4326);
END;
$function$
```

Is it possible that there is a timeout for functions? The spatial query may take a couple of seconds (spatial index is set).

Comment: Which SQL client are you using? pgAdmin is know to truncate long values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I work in python and use psycopg2

Comment: Maybe it will help if you change return value of function from json to jsonb?

Comment: I had such bug with node.js if returned value had `UTF` - try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to your python script

Comment: Try to call it using `psql` like `copy (select mj_dgg_regions_BB_geojson(<parameters here>)) to stdout;` If all Ok then problems at the Python side.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I tried it, but unfortunately it did not help

Comment: @Abelisto please see my last edit

Comment: What does the function `mj_dgg_regions_BB()` do? Can you post that code as well?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  It is a spatial query, you can see it in Edit 2.

Comment: @Michael BTW why do you use `plpgsql` for functions that contains only single query? Personally I have no ideas why the functions with query works in different way then the query alone. But try also to change your function(s) from `language plpgsql` to simple `language sql`.

Comment: @Michael PS: Also you are mixing `JSON` and `JSONB` types in your code: function returns `JSON` from the query that returns `JSONB` which built from `JSON`.

Comment: @Abelisto. Thanks! Indeed, this was the problem. It has to be consistently JSON or JSONB and it works. Still interesting that the function behaves differently...

Comment: @Michael So, problem was solved? Alleluia! :) Obviously I can not reproduce the problem here. If you interesting in it, you could to perform the last test: save the plain query result into some table column of `JSONB` type and then create test function which returns `JSON` as result of select from this table. If the problem will be reproducible, you could to post it as a bug, I think.